# Need help creating a aspx page demonstrating opening a SSRS report through a url

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

first: I am not a web-developer, my experience with asp.net is marginal. That is why I seek help. 
I need instructions how to create a simple asp page that will

- list a hierarchical view of  all reports on a specific location.
- These reports must then be transformed into hyperlinks that will open
  that report without asking for credentials
- On opening the report the page must know which parameters are
  necessary in the report, what type they are and whether they should
  be shown.
- This should be done without using the reportviewer web control

I figured that I could use Listchildren() to get a list of reports.
I know that, when you know name and location of a report, you can open it through a url.
I know that is is possible to iterate through the parameters of a report and show/hide them in your page
But how to do that in a asp.net page?

I can not find any real simple noob level instructions for what should not be so hard....

Can somebody provide me with some examples/hints/easy-to-follow-step-by-step-reporting-and-programming-for-dummies-instructions  on a noob-level?

I am using VS2012, SQL 2012 Standard, Windows Server 2012, IIS8

Comment: You're trying to do/cover too much at once, get to grips with creating the page first. For this, any asp .net for beginners tutorial will do. Then you can move onto being as specific as possible with your questions.

Comment: why not report viewer control?

Comment: @DeeMac Well, actually, I succeeded in creating a page that says 'hello world'.. And from there I do find several tutorials and stuff but somehow they all seem to assume that, if you can put a 'hello world'onm the screen you also know what webreferences are, what a .cs and/or .vb does, how to write connectionstrings and what to put where in which file.... Which I, unfortunately, do not even though I did see 'hello world  on my screen :)

Comment: @Henrov - all of the topics you've mentioned there are going to be fundamental to what you're trying to achieve. I agree, when you're learning asp .net development in the early stages - resources really do make a lot of assumptions and it's often difficult to get a tutorial that will take you from the basics in an approachable way, but you won't be able to skip those topics and do what you're wanting to do here without tackling things like cs files (massively integral to asp .net) and references. I think the real issue for you is finding a good book that will acquaint you with asp .net dev.

Comment: @VinayPandey It plays havoc with page-layout, it displays ugly parameter prompts, it has issues with printing, does not play well with IE 11 (even in compat. mode) and does not offer the flexibility we need. fe conditionally how/hide parameters based on user opening the reports. Theoretical research shows a lot of our issues can be solved by creating our own page but within my organisation I cannot convince people to make that transition based on articles. They need visual proof. That is why me who is NOT a webdeveloper needs to set up something simple to convince people that it works.

Comment: @DeeMac I was afraid that you were going to say that. I am even more scared that you are probably right :s

Comment: @Henrov - yep, it's probably best if you're going to go down the route of developing something like this in asp .net you learn it first. Although, if your approach is to throw yourself in the deep end, I'd propose you look at this article which does exactly what you're wanting to do: http://pendsevikram.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/integrating-sql-server-reporting.html - EDIT: I think this uses report viewer actually. Apologies. If I find a better link I'll post it shortly.